# Show My Current Game Object Inside ui In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

Im so new in unity and have a stupid problem.
i have a scroll view For Show My next Enemies, it almost working good but problem is i want show images of enemy .
i copy enemy game object and add to game object's of info box as image.

[image: game image]

as you see, all ui element hide in scrolling but the game object is top of them all...

i tryed and change sorting order of gaqme object but it didnt work and it hides and never visible or always visible...

is there a way i get image of game object in runtime and show image?
or in editor

sorry for bad english*

Comment: i recall there are a bunch of options about making a sprite from a game object to do just this sort of thing.. i dont have any links to hand, google will. I remember using one they were quick and easy

Comment: nice it is good tip, so i should work on "converting gameobject to sprite"
thanks i gona try it